# PHP date difference error

Tags: php, datetime

```
$startDate = new DateTime("2016-06-01");
$endDate = new DateTime("2016-06-30");
$diff = date_diff($startDate,$endDate);
$differenceYear = $diff->format("%y");
$differenceMonth = $diff->format("%m");
$difference = $differenceYear*12 + $differenceMonth;
echo $difference;
```

Above code will output 0 as the result. But when I change those two dates to 2016-12-01 and 2016-12-31 the code gives 1 as the output. Why is that happening?

When I check this code online php editor it gives the right answer. But when I copied it to my local machine the answer shows wrong. Online editor has **US/Pacific** as the timezone. My pc has **Asia/Kolkata**  timezone. Both has the same PHP version

Comment: The code outputs `1` for me. Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: @modsfabio Its about the timezone dude..

Comment: dear as june month have only 30 days and you pass 2016-06-31, that's why you getting error

Comment: Try using `DateTime::createFromFormat` and pass the format of your date

Comment: @MahipalPatel Do you even read the question? His problem is that 2016-12-01 and 2016-12-31 show a `1` month difference instead of `30 days`

Comment: have you tried var_dumping/echoing each variable after a change or declaration? to see the full process of your script and see how the data is being manipulated

Comment: i read his question as date_diff return correct answer but they pass wrong date in one month so thats his answer is differ for both dates just print_r($diff) variable and check all parameter

Comment: @CBroe Do you post an answer? your suggestion with UTC works. Feel free to use this 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/fsIHt

Comment: "1 month" has such a wishy-washy definition that it's extremely hard to ever be able to clearly say that two dates are "x months apart"…

Comment: @MahipalPatel for PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) module, `2016-06-31` is a perfectly valid date and it doesn't produce any error. It just happens that everybody prefers to refer to it as `the 1st of July` (`2016-07-01`).

Comment: @MahipalPatel Sorry for the typo. It should be 06-30. But still get the wrong output

Answer (score 3):

Using my default timezone (`Europe/Bucharest`), a `print_r($diff)` produces:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 0
    [days] => 30
)
# I removed the other components as they are irrelevant to the question
# and they are 0 anyway.
```

It means: "`1` month and `0` days" (the `m` and `d` properties), `30` days in total (the `days` property).

Using `Asia/Kolkata` as the default time zone it prints:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 30
    [days] => 30
)
# Again, all the other object properties are 0 and irrelevant for the question
```

This one means: "`0` months and `30` days", `30` days in total.

---

As you can see, the total number of days (the `days` property) is the same (`30`) and correct.

Regarding the *"1 month and 0 days"* vs. *"0 months and 30 days"*, both of them are correct and incorrect on the same time.

What's the definition of **"one month"**? It can be anything between `28` and `31` days. This means, *"1 month and 0 days"* is equal to *"0 months and 28 days"*, *"0 months and 29 days"* a.s.o. **on the same time**.

---

The question title reads **"PHP date difference error"** -- there is no error in the PHP date difference. It is just a loose definition of the term ["month"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month) in the human languages and cultures.

Comment: So what should i use as the answer. But the thing is same period gives me wrong answers. **2016-06-01** and **2016-06-30** gives 0 and **2016-12-01** and **2016-12-31** gives 1 as the output

Answer (score 1):

This is a timezone issue. I’d recommend that you create your DateTime objects from date strings such as `2016-12-01 00:00:00 +00:00`, so that you will always be working in UTC.

```
$startDate = new DateTime("2016-12-01  00:00:00 +00:00");
$endDate = new DateTime("2016-12-31  00:00:00 +00:00"); 
$diff = date_diff($startDate,$endDate);
$differenceYear = $diff->format("%y");
$differenceMonth = $diff->format("%m");
var_dump($differenceYear,$differenceMonth);
$difference = $differenceYear*12 + $differenceMonth;
echo $difference;
```

(Code taken from Xatenev’s comment, otherwise this answer looks so short ;-)